# Google Analytic

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I am just beginner for Google Analytic API.
Now i am testing this code.

```
public static string HttpGetRequest(string url, string[] headers)
{
    String result;
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
    if (headers.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (var header in headers)
        {
            request.Headers.Add(header);
        }
    }
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Upper code run correctly when **URL** value is

**https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxx&dimensions=ga:browser,ga:browserVersion,ga:city,ga:date,ga:hour,ga:visitCount,ga:visitorType&metrics=ga:entrances,ga:uniquePageviews&start-date=2011-09-18&end-date=2011-10-18&sort=-ga:entrances&max-results=50**

And then this upper code return correct information.
But when i change **URL** value to

**https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data?ids=ga:xxxxxxxx&dimensions=ga:pagePath,ga:browser,ga:browserVersion,ga:city,ga:date,ga:hour,ga:visitCount,ga:visitorType&metrics=ga:entrances,ga:uniquePageviews&start-date=2011-09-18&end-date=2011-10-18&sort=-ga:entrances&max-results=50**

It  give this error.

```
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
```

The only thing differences between these two URL is **ga:pagePath**.

Please let me know how could I avoid these error.
Any kind of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure ga:pagePath is even valid the error would indicate its not.

Comment: sorry Ramhound, i am not clear what you would like to say.

Comment: I am so sure that this error occur only when I put URL value to ga:pagePath.

Comment: Don't you need to include a ga:pagePath filter too?

Comment: I want to see information about which pages of my web site users view.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, reduce one dimension, and it will work.
Only 7 dimensions are allowed, you used 8.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see how many visitors visited each page you should include only the dimension `ga:pagePath`. Seems like to me that you're trying to fetch everything you want with a single query when in fact you should be doing multiple queries. Also you can test your queries on the [query explorer](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataExplorer.html):

Answer (score 0):

First check with [query explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/), if it's working or not, then check your code. 400 error is not shown only for this problem. **May be a problem in authentication**